# Stream youtube video in vlc using youtube_dl library and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

I'm trying to embed `youtube-dl -o - "<youtube link>" | vlc -` into python code using the `youtube_dl` library to stream directly to vlc media player, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if youtube-dl supports writing to stdout, or if vlc supports reading from stdin. It's quite unlikely IMO, since seeking through the file would seem like a natural thing a video player would do, but it might be worth trying the following:

```
youtube-dl -o /dev/stdout "<youtube link>" | vlc /dev/stdin
```

Another possibility worth trying would be to make a fifo

```
mkfifo fifo.avi
youtube-dl -o fifo.avi "<youtube link>" &
vlc fifo.avi
```

Ultimately I think you need something between your youtube-dl, and vlc to translate your streaming download into a streaming protocol that vlc supports.

Having that said, check out this: https://www.vlchelp.com/play-youtube-videos-vlc-media-player/. Perhaps you can achieve your objective without youtube-dl.